Access denied when running PS script with account thats member of local admin group
I have several servers that's members of a workgroup.
I need to change the password for these.
For test I created a local account and joined it to the local administrators group. Then i started powershell with this newly created account.
$NewPass = Read-Host -Prompt “Provide New Password” -AsSecureString
Get-LocalUser "test" | Set-LocalUser -Password $NewPass

If I run this in the PS console I get

Set-LocalUser : Access denied.
At line:1 char:24


Get-LocalUser "test" | Set-LocalUser -Password $NewPass

If I run a short PS function to see if I'm elevated it returns false
function Test-IsElevated {
    $id = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
    $p = New-Object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($id)
    if ($p.IsInRole([System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator))
    { Write-Output $true }
    else
    { Write-Output $false }
}

The only way to run this script is to add start powershell -verb Runas but then UAC needs concent before open the new PS console which would be problematic when I run the script remotely.
Any ideas if there are any other ways of doing this?
Appreciate the help, spend many hours on google here..
Thanks

This post: https://superuser.com:how-to-run-a-powershell-script-as-administrator shows a few solutions to run a PowerShell script (elevated) as administrator.

Thanks, but all the solutions there will do the same as I've tried - Open a new PS console as administrator, but the problem then is that UAC will appear, and you have to consent?

@DanielOlsson Yes it always will do locally as that's how Windows security works, there's no way to prevent that. Remotely can be different in certain circumstances, eg via New-PSSession / Enter-PSSession you end up elevated if you're connected with admin credentials, but that is likely AFTER you've been prompted for and entered the creds for the remote computer.
